# Why does altering the height attribute for the input box on a sitefeed web part break its validation?

Tags: 2013, css, custom-masterpage, newsfeed, sitefeed

I'm working on a solution for a client which includes a newsfeed web part on the site homepage. For some reason the character limit for a newsfeed post isn't being enforced,  by which I mean the warning text isn't appearing when the user exceed 512 characters and the page ends up hanging.

We are using a custom master page and some styling on the site and if I switch the site to use a standard master page i.e. oslo.master then the newsfeed behaves correctly. Clearly something in our alterations to the site look and feel has knocked out the newsfeed validation.

UPDATE:
I have worked out that the problem is caused by one of our custom css, specifically this line. If I remove it everything works as expected:

```
#ms-microblogdiv .ms-microfeed-postBox {   
    height: 100px; 
}
```

Does anyone out there have any idea why this might be the case?

Many thanks

Comment: Hi Robert - unfortunately the reason I am posting here is because I don't know what the relevant parts of css, html and javascript are :-( If you can tell me how the sitefeed validation works then I will gladly pull out the relevant code and post it here. I'm really hoping for some tips as to where to start looking i.e. what js handles the validation, what page elements it relies on etc. so I can check whether any of the custom styling we have been provided with encroaches on it.

Comment: This css does not break the feed in my environment. It still validates the input correctly. What patch level is your SharePoint farm?

Answer (score 0):

Just Change:

from:

```
#ms-microblogdiv .ms-microfeed-postBox 
{   
    height: 100px;
}
```

to

```
#ms-microblogdiv .ms-microfeed-postBox 
{   
    min-height: 100px; 
}
```

In this case with the css is trying to increase the feed box, but the css is blocking.

I translate this message with google translator, rs.

Hugs